# Get Items Feeds4J Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, feed

Im from php, so  i want to lear java.
In php in a for loop if i want to create an array i just do

```
$items = $this->getItems();
for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++)
{
 $myarrayitems[$i] = $items[$i];
}

return $myarrayitems;
```

But in java i got arrayoutofexponsion or like that.

here is the code im trying

```
public String[] getItems(String url) throws Exception
{
URL rss = new URL(url);
Feed feed = FeedParser.parse(rss);
int items = feed.getItemCount();
int a = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) 
{
FeedItem item = feed.getItem(i);
String title[i] =  item.getTitle();
}

return title;

}
```

How can i return title as array an make an var_dump of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define *title* as an array before using using it:

```
String title = new String[ARRAY_DIMENSION];
```

If you don't know *ARRAY_DIMENSION* you could use this:

```
List<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or this, if you do not mind String order in the ArrayList:

```
Collection<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: but i dont know how big the array_dimension is so i cant insert an 10 or 20

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the array with the right number of elements to start with. Something like this:

```
public String[] getItems(String url) throws Exception
{
    URL rss = new URL(url);
    Feed feed = FeedParser.parse(rss);
    int items = feed.getItemCount();
    // We know how many elements we need, so create the array
    String[] titles = new String[items];

    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++) 
    {
        titles[i] = feed.getItem(i).getTitle();
    }

    return titles;    
}
```

A potentially nicer alternative, however, is to return a `List<String>` instead of a string array. I don't know the `FeedParser` API, but if you can iterate over the items instead you could do something like:

```
public List<String> getItems(String url) throws Exception
{
    URL rss = new URL(url);
    Feed feed = FeedParser.parse(rss);
    List<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Item item : feed)
    {
        titles.add(item.getTitle());
    }    
    return titles;    
}
```

This will work even if you don't know how many items there are to start with. When Java eventually gets concise closures, you may well be able to express this even more simply, as you would in C# with LINQ :)